# How to use Redux's Provider with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been following the ReduxJS documentation here: [Usage with React](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)

At the end of the document it mentions usage of the provider object, I have wrapped my App component in the provider like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import RootReducer from './app/reducers'
import App from './app/app'

const store = createStore(RootReducer)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

However, that's where the documentation ends. How do I pickup the store provided by provider within the components?

Comment: It shows you how to connect components to the store earlier in the tutorial - look at the section marked 'Container Components'.

Comment: @JoeClay So you still need to use connect?

Comment: `connect` is the best/most reliable way to do it, unless you have a very good reason to go lower level (the guide mentions that `connect` has extra performance optimizations). That said, if you really want to access the store directly, `Provider` makes it so all child components can do so via the context - `this.context.store` inside your component should return this instance.

Comment: I'll write a better formatted version of that up as an answer with some examples.

Comment: @JacobMason You can’t use ```connect()``` without wrapping the root component in ```<Provider>```.

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The best way to access your store through a component is using the `connect()` function, [as described in the documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options). This allows you to map state and action creators to your component, and have them passed in automatically as your store updates. Additionally, by default it will pass in `dispatch` as `this.props.dispatch`. Here's an example from the docs:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setVisibilityFilter } from '../actions'
import Link from '../components/Link'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    active: ownProps.filter === state.visibilityFilter
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(ownProps.filter))
    }
  }
}

const FilterLink = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Link)

export default FilterLink
```

Note that `connect` actually creates a new component that wraps around your existing one! This pattern is called [Higher-Order Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.c1wydli6a), and is generally the preferred way of extending a component's functionality in React (over stuff like inheritance or mixins).

Due to it having quite a few performance optimizations and generally being less likely to cause bugs, the Redux devs almost always recommend using `connect` over accessing the store directly - however, if you have a *very* good reason to need lower level access, the `Provider` component makes it so all its children can access the store through [`this.context`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html):

```
class MyComponent {
  someMethod() {
    doSomethingWith(this.context.store);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh man, not knowing what to google for is the worst.  `this.context` is what I needed.  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: @Freedom_Ben: I know the feeling! Glad you found what it was you were looking for.

Comment: what is ownProps.filter? I don't see the filter prop in the Link comp in teh todo example

Comment: @SuperUberDuper: `ownProps` refers to the props on the wrapper component, not the original one - you can see the usage of FilterLink (and the filter prop) here: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#componentsfooterjs

Comment: Thx, also why is React imported in footer.js, I don't see it used

Comment: @SuperUberDuper: When JSX gets compiled, `<Component />` turns into `React.createElement(Component)`. So technically it is being used, just not in an obvious way :)

Comment: @SuperUberDuper: Yeah, I think a lot of people get tripped up by that to begin with.

Comment: what is the rational behind this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125980/discussion-between-joe-clay-and-superuberduper).

Answer (score 17):

Thanks for the answer, but it is missing one crucial bit, which is actually in the documentation.

> If contextTypes is not defined, then context will be an empty object.

So I had to add the following for it to work for me:

```
  static contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }
```

Comment: that in the component? so in the render function `this.contextTypes.store.getState()` for example?

Comment: Yes, this is inside the component.
And inside the render() method you use:

   this.context.store

Comment: Wow, I was stuck for a whole week trying to figure this out!