# Am I getting the state value correctly in Redux?

Tags: redux

I'm getting the value of a component through redux store's getState(). Here's what it looks like

```
handleFormSubmit (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // have to get this.context because my prop value doesn't update with a change in child component
  const value = this.context.store.getState();
  if (value._root.entries[3][1]._root.entries[1][1]){
    browserHistory.push('/place/' + value._root.entries[3][1]._root.entries[1][1]);
  }
```

To get redux values, do we really need to have this complex code?

```
value._root.entries[3][1]._root.entries[1][1]
```

**Edit** Thanks to Abdul for mentioning the connect libraries. I'll add the code here

```
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
```

Here's connect...

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SimpleForm);
```

Comment: Aren't you not using the Connect and Provider APIs provided by 'react-redux'?

Comment: I am! Let me update the answer with connect, but I'm still not sure how to get the context state.

Comment: @AbdulSamad The prop value doesn't update with an update in a child component. So that's why I get context

Comment: this question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864957/how-to-use-reduxs-provider-with-react

Comment: With connect, you are subscribing your component to the store listening for updates and the entire store is passed down to your component as props. Then you can tweak the store to get what you want.

Comment: So the prop in the parent component should automatically update with a dispatch in the child component? I guess I'm using the store with this.context.store? Just seems like there should be an easier way to get a buried value within store.

Comment: Which of your components, parent or child, is connected to the store via the Connect method?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

Use the .get on the store from getState

```
const value = this.context.store.getState();
const home = value.get('home');
const getPlace = home.get('place_id');
```