# Using Redux Provider Store with Reactjs - error Store does not have a valid reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am embarking on a project which involves using typescript/react/redux together with golden layout. I'm having some issues getting Redux's Provider Store working with react. I've done some previous searching, and came across the following question:

[How to use Redux's Provider with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864957/how-to-use-reduxs-provider-with-react)

I've been following the advice given in the answers to that question, to write my own code, as seen below:

```
import React from 'react';
import GoldenLayout from 'golden-layout';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import Default from '../modules/m-Default/Default';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

interface GoldenLayoutWrapperProps {}

interface GoldenLayoutWrapperState {}

class GoldenLayoutWrapper extends React.Component <GoldenLayoutWrapperProps, GoldenLayoutWrapperState> {

    public layout;
    static contextTypes = {
        store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    private wrapComponent(Component, store) {
        class Wrapped extends React.Component {
            render () {
                return (
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <Component {...this.props}/>
                    </Provider>
                )
            }
        }
        return Wrapped;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var layout = new GoldenLayout(this.layoutConfig, this.layout);
        layout.registerComponent('Default', this.wrapComponent(Default, this.context.store));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="golden-layout-wrapper" ref={input => this.layout = input}/>
        )
    }

    private layoutConfig = {}
}

export default GoldenLayoutWrapper;
```

You can see, basically what my class is doing, is setting up a golden layout interface by registering react components with golden layout. So that this works with redux, I've defined the `wrapComponent` function to return the react component to be registered, but wrapped in a Redux Provider.

I followed the pattern outlined in the question I linked above, using `context.store` and `store: PropTypes.object.isRequired`

However, when I run the application, I get the following error from my browser console:

```
Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.
```

Under this, in my browser console, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined at new GoldenLayoutWrapper
```

Still being new to Redux, I'm not 100% sure what this means, but it seems to me that `store` is undefined, and hence does not have a valid reducer. But, according to the question I liked above, this should work.

What could be the problem here?

Here's my code for the root app and root reducer:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Store, createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import GoldenlayoutWrapper from './main/GoldenLayoutWrapper';

import rootReducer from './main/rootReducer';

const initialState = {};
const store: Store<any> = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <GoldenlayoutWrapper/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I've left rootReducers empty so that developers in the future can add their code to it:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

// Import your reducers here

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    // Add your reducers here
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**I've also tried the following:**

In my root app, defining store as `const store:<any> = createStore(state=>state, initialState)` rather than `const store:<any> = createStore(rootReducer, initialState)`

And in my root reducer, trying to specify a blank reducer: `blank: function(state, action) {if (state == null) state = [] return state;}`

But neither of these worked. I got the same error as above.

Comment: how is your store looks like? Is it defined by you or you assume that it should come from somewhere provided to you?:)

Comment: Add the code where you call `createStore`. The error means that when creating the store you did not provide a reducer for it.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela I've edited my post with that information

Comment: @trixn I've added that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is base use of the `Redux`, see if your code has all ingredients required:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';


// ACTIONS
const SAMPLE_ACTION_TYPE = 'gd:SAMPLE_ACTION_TYPE';
const sampleAction = (payload) => ({
    type: SAMPLE_ACTION_TYPE,
    payload
});


// REDUCER
const sampleReducer = (state={}, action) => {
    return state;
};
const sampleTwoReducer = (state=[],action) => {
    return state;
}

// STORE
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        sample:sampleReducer,
        sampleTwo:sampleTwoReducer
    })
);

// SUBSCRIBE
store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log("STORE STATE", store.getState());
});

// DISPATCH SOME ACTIONS
store.dispatch(sampleAction());
```

Above creates following output:

```
STORE STATE 
{sample: {…}, sampleTwo: Array(0)}
sample:
__proto__:Object
sampleTwo:Array(0) length:0
__proto__:Array(0)
__proto__:Object
```

but changing the code to:

```
// STORE
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        sample:null,
        sampleTwo:null
    })
);
```

produces the same error, check what is passed to `combineReducer`

** EDIT **
To provide the store to the components you do two things, first set the `Provider`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MyApp />
    </Provider >, document.getElementById('app'));
```

then in your component you are calling High Order Functions `connect` this will connect your component to the store, detailed description in [the docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md)

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import React from 'react';
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    notMapped = (payload) => {
        this.props.dispatch(sampleAction(payload));
    }
    render() {
        const {sample, mappedFunction} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{sample}</p>
                <button onClick={() => {
                    mappedFunction("test");
                }}>Call mapped Function</button>
                <button onClick={() => {
                    this.notMapped("test");
                }}>Call NOT mapped Function</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    mappedFunction: (payload) => dispatch(sampleAction(payload))
});
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    sample: state.sample
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);// connect
```

Comment: How does the store get passed around to components and providers?